# How to handle line breaks in value when inserting it to table in mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a table with two varchar/text fields, I have data with line breaks for both the two fields, how can I insert them correctly into mysql? at the moment mysql is throwing out error:

here is an example:

```
insert into usecase(description, comment) value('Use Case : 1 of 65
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
in sea, natum's cetero (an per)

', '
Lorem ipsum
Consul appetere
')
```

> Error: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'usecase(description, comment) value('Use Case : 1 of
>   65 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,' at line 1 MySQL connection is closed

**[UPDATE]**

This is part of a python3 program.

```
    query = f"insert into usecase(description, comment) value(\'{description}\', \'{comment}\')"

    print(query)
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
```

Thank you very much.

**[UPDATE/ANSWER]:**
**Thanks to @Anonymous and @nbk, using a parameterized query is the fix, below is the working code:**

```
    query = "insert into usecase(description, comment) value(%s, %s)"

    args = description, comment

    if (connection.is_connected()):
        c1 = connection.cursor()
        c1.execute(query, args)
        connection.commit()
        print("New case inserted.")
```

Comment: why is this tagged with python?

Comment: You should not use [Reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) for table- or fieldnames.

Comment: You need to escape your values. Can you show the Python code that runs this statement?

Comment: sure, thank you, updated the OP.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't name a table "case". By the way, nice second draft of your question.

Comment: good catch, corrected the typo on the table name, error remains same.

Comment: And please use parameterized queries...

Comment: As far as i can see is your tick in natum's c     which is causing the most problem but as always of you use **parametrized querys** your problmes should g away